# Porting C# Func<> to Java- Math Equation

Tags: c#, java, porting

I'm porting a C# Library to Java (for nonlinear regression, original code [here](http://www.trentfguidry.net/post/2011/12/10/Implementing-Levenberg-Marquardt-algorithm-nonlinear-least-squares-regression-multiple-weighted-simultaneous-functions-in-C-sharp.aspx)). The library uses the Func<> class, which doesn't exist in Java. I.E. (A, B, C, and D, and time are parameters used for regression, don't need fixed.)

```
Func<double>[] regressionFunctions = new Func<double>[]
{() => A * Math.Exp(time) * Math.Sin(B * time),
() => C * Math.Exp(time) * Math.Cos(D * time)};
```

What I would like to do is convert this to Java code. I saw something about creating an anonymous inner class, but I'm not certain of the correct usage for this particular situation. I would like the equation to be evaluable at a later time (for a particular value of t). Do I need a new class, an interface, or what would be the best method?
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own interface, and use anonymous implementations to port the code:

```
// Declaring the interface
interface FuncDouble {
    double calculate();
}

public LevenbergMarquardt(FuncDouble[] regressionFunctions, ...) {
    // Using the functor:
    double functionValue = _regressionFunctions[i].calculate()
}

// Declaring an array of functors:
FuncDouble[] regressionFunctions = new FuncDouble[] {
    new FuncDouble() {
        public double calculate() {
            return A * Math.Exp(time) * Math.Sin(B * time);
        }
    }
,   new FuncDouble() {
        public double calculate() {
            return C * Math.Exp(time) * Math.Cos(D * time);
        }
    }
};
```

In order for the implementation to work, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `time` variables must be either instance/class variables, or be `final` local variables.

Comment: Thanks so much! If I declare the parameters `final`, will that stop me from changing the value at a later time (i.e. `A.setValue(somevalue)`? And when I try using the code declaring the array, Java gives me a "generic array creation" error. Any tips?

Comment: @user1469531 There is a pending edit on the question which requires a second approval, so you cannot see the change at the moment. The problem with the array creation is that `public claculate()` should be `public double calculate()`.

Comment: @user1469531 Making `A` final does not make the object the `A` references immutable. In other words, it prevents you from writing `A = new SomeClass()`, but it does not prevent you from writing `A.setValue(newValue)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And I did change the double thing. The error it is still giving me is in the line where I declare the array. Updated code following: `Func<Double>[] regressionFunctions = new Func<Double>[1]; regressionFunctions[0] = new Func<Double>() { @Override public double calculate() { return IL.getValue() - I0.getValue() * (Math.exp((e * voltage.getValue() + current.getValue() * Rs.getValue()) / (A.getValue() * k * T.getValue())) - 1); } };`

Comment: @user1469531 If you are creating a generic array, you should drop the type argument, like this: `Func<Double>[] regressionFunctions = new Func[] {/*elements*/}`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is already an interface for it in the library, but you could do something like this:

```
interface Func<T> {
    T appy();
}
```

and then say:

```
Func<Double>[] funcs = new Func<Double>[] {
    new Func<Double> { @override Double apply() { ... } },
    new Func<Double> { @override Double apply() { ... } }
};
```

and then later call apply on them. Note: I write a lot more c# than java and don't have a java compiler handy so the syntax may be off for that array instantiation - but hopefully you catch my meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create an interface with generics and pass implementations of it.  There are ways around "doesn't exist in Java".

```
public interface Func<T> {
   T evaluate(Object...params);
}
```

You might also look at the `Callable<T>` class.